# Mute ActiveStorage Logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

ActiveStorage floods my dev logs so i'm drowning in requests for images on a page. Is there a way to mute active storage or atleast reduce the log entries so that I can use my logs again?

For example, for each of the images on a page that are accessed via ActiveStorage, I get one of these:

```
2018-09-03 11:07:42.181697 I [75455:70130232359340 log_subscriber.rb:12] (2.365ms) ActiveStorage::DiskController -- Completed #show -- {
        :controller => "ActiveStorage::DiskController",
            :action => "show",
            :params => {
        "content_type" => "image/jpeg",
         "disposition" => "inline; filename=\"faded-flip.jpg\"; filename*=UTF-8''faded-flip.jpg",
         "encoded_key" => "eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaEpJbk4yWVhKcFlXNTBjeTh6TnpRMVlqSmtZaTB3WlRCakxUUTVaRFV0WW1Ga01DMWxNRFl4TWpFd09Ua3dOMkl2TkdRME1qQTBNR1EzTjJaaE5UZ3pOVFU1WXpSbVpqaGlOVFpoWVdVd01ESmhabVJqWW1GaE5HTmxPRFV3WXpneU1UUmhPVEpsWlRVNVl6bGlPRGs0WVFZNkJrVlUiLCJleHAiOiIyMDE4LTA5LTAzVDEwOjEyOjMyLjUwN1oiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--b9eed7f4cf3d71fcb697429188e1a1a74ba88bec",
            "filename" => "faded-flip"
    },
            :format => "JPEG",
            :method => "GET",
              :path => "/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaEpJbk4yWVhKcFlXNTBjeTh6TnpRMVlqSmtZaTB3WlRCakxUUTVaRFV0WW1Ga01DMWxNRFl4TWpFd09Ua3dOMkl2TkdRME1qQTBNR1EzTjJaaE5UZ3pOVFU1WXpSbVpqaGlOVFpoWVdVd01ESmhabVJqWW1GaE5HTmxPRFV3WXpneU1UUmhPVEpsWlRVNVl6bGlPRGs0WVFZNkJrVlUiLCJleHAiOiIyMDE4LTA5LTAzVDEwOjEyOjMyLjUwN1oiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--b9eed7f4cf3d71fcb697429188e1a1a74ba88bec/faded-flip.jpg",
            :status => 200,
      :view_runtime => 0.69,
        :db_runtime => 0.0,
    :status_message => "OK"
}
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Sep/2018:11:07:41 BST] "GET /rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaEpJbk4yWVhKcFlXNTBjeTh6TnpRMVlqSmtZaTB3WlRCakxUUTVaRFV0WW1Ga01DMWxNRFl4TWpFd09Ua3dOMkl2TkdRME1qQTBNR1EzTjJaaE5UZ3pOVFU1WXpSbVpqaGlOVFpoWVdVd01ESmhabVJqWW1GaE5HTmxPRFV3WXpneU1UUmhPVEpsWlRVNVl6bGlPRGs0WVFZNkJrVlUiLCJleHAiOiIyMDE4LTA5LTAzVDEwOjEyOjMyLjUwN1oiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--b9eed7f4cf3d71fcb697429188e1a1a74ba88bec/faded-flip.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22faded-flip.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27faded-flip.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 21345
http://localhost:3000/users/password/new -> /rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaEpJbk4yWVhKcFlXNTBjeTh6TnpRMVlqSmtZaTB3WlRCakxUUTVaRFV0WW1Ga01DMWxNRFl4TWpFd09Ua3dOMkl2TkdRME1qQTBNR1EzTjJaaE5UZ3pOVFU1WXpSbVpqaGlOVFpoWVdVd01ESmhabVJqWW1GaE5HTmxPRFV3WXpneU1UUmhPVEpsWlRVNVl6bGlPRGs0WVFZNkJrVlUiLCJleHAiOiIyMDE4LTA5LTAzVDEwOjEyOjMyLjUwN1oiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--b9eed7f4cf3d71fcb697429188e1a1a74ba88bec/faded-flip.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22faded-flip.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27faded-flip.jpg
2018-09-03 11:07:42.234412 D [75455:70130203086520 log_subscriber.rb:8] ActiveStorage::DiskController -- Processing #show
2018-09-03 11:07:42.239153 I [75455:70130203086520 log_subscriber.rb:96] Rails --   FlatDisk Storage (0.1ms) Downloaded file from key: variants/ef6bca1d-bfd1-485e-b7cd-88a0e1e95404/4d42040d77fa583559c4ff8b56aae002afdcbaa4ce850c8214a92ee59c9b898a
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this as simplest (maybe but not bulletproof) solution for easier development. It uses standard Rails log and only replaces its default formatter. Works on Rails 6, probably will work on Rails 5 too.

Place code bellow into `config/environments/development.rb`:

```rb
Rails.application.configure do
    .
    .
    .

  class MyLogFormatter
    def initialize
      # Suppress is an array of request uuids. Each listed uuid means no messages from this request.
      @suppress = []
    end

    def call(severity, datetime, progname, message)
      # Get uuid, which we need to properly distinguish between parallel requests.
      # Also remove uuid information from log (that's why we match the rest of message)
      matches = /\[([0-9a-zA-Z\-_]+)\] (.*)/m.match(message)

      if matches
        uuid = matches[1]
        message = matches[2]

        if @suppress.include?(uuid) && message.start_with?("Completed ")
          # Each request in Rails log ends with "Completed ..." message, so do suppressed messages.
          @suppress.delete(uuid)
          return nil

        elsif message.start_with?("Processing by ActiveStorage::DiskController#show", "Processing by ActiveStorage::BlobsController#show", "Processing by ActiveStorage::RepresentationsController#show", "Started GET \"/rails/active_storage/disk/", "Started GET \"/rails/active_storage/blobs/", "Started GET \"/rails/active_storage/representations/")
          # When we use ActiveStorage disk provider, there are three types of request: Disk requests, Blobs requests and Representation requests.
          # These three types we would like to hide.
          @suppress << uuid
          return nil

        elsif !@suppress.include?(uuid)
          # All messages, which are not suppressed, print. New line must be added here.
          return "#{message}\n"
        end

      else
        # Return message as it is (including new line at the end)
        return "#{message}\n"
      end

    end
  end

  config.log_tags = [:uuid]
  config.log_formatter = MyLogFormatter.new
    .
    .
    .
end
```

Comment: Thnx for the answer did you maybe have the problem of these not being muted? 

Disk Storage (0.0ms) Checked if file exists at key: variants
Disk Storage (1.6ms) Generated URL for file at key: variants/

Maybe something is changed in ActiveStorage now quite sure

Answer (score 8):

According to the article of [EvilMartians](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/rails-5-2-active-storage-and-beyond) I've set

`config.active_record.verbose_query_logs` option to `false` inside `application.rb`.

It partly solves the problem.

It seems like Active Storage people consider the most verbose logging very important. So now logs about files take the same size on the disk as stored files.

And the most irritating thing is the level of these messages is INFO. I can't understand why it's not DEBUG...

Answer (score 8):

I'm using [Lograge Gem](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge) to hide those requests.

```
config.lograge.ignore_actions = [
  "ActiveStorage::DiskController#show",
  "ActiveStorage::RepresentationsController#show"
]
```

Comment: Did you maybe try to mute: "Disk Storage (0.6ms) Generated URL for file at key:

Comment: Also add `ActiveStorage::Representations::RedirectController#show`

Answer (score 4):

One thing I've done to make the logs slightly quieter is to filter some ActiveStorage-related parameters from the logs. I added `:encoded_key`, `:signed_blob_id`, and `:variation_key` to the filtered parameters in `config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [
  :password,
  # Filter ActiveStorage blob keys so that the logs aren't full of as much stuff.
  :encoded_key,
  :signed_blob_id,
  :variation_key
]
```

Before:

```
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSm5kbUZ5YVdGdWRITXZiMDVvUjNCblJIQm9RVWd6YWtGeFFWUlpPV0Z3U2tWSUwyRTBZemd3WVRCallUUTJZalJtWmpObE16Vm1aV1l5TVRFelltWmxPREptWlRsalpUbGhNalE0WmpWaE9UZ3hZVEk1WkdVek5XUmxNemt4Wm1VNE1HUUdPZ1pGVkRvUVpHbHpjRzl6YVhScGIyNUpJazFwYm14cGJtVTdJR1pwYkdWdVlXMWxQU0kzWDJaaGEyVnlYMk52ZG1WeUxtcHdaeUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuTjE5bVlXdGxjbDlqYjNabGNpNXFjR2NHT3daVU9oRmpiMjUwWlc1MFgzUjVjR1ZKSWc5cGJXRm5aUzlxY0dWbkJqc0dWQT09IiwiZXhwIjoiMjAxOS0wMi0yNFQyMDoxNTo1MS45OTFaIiwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--c8b11cdaa201d28d585f62aaa7c8cf6af75e7cab/7_faker_cover.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%227_faker_cover.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%277_faker_cover.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-24 13:10:52 -0700
Processing by ActiveStorage::DiskController#show as JPEG
  Parameters: {"content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "disposition"=>"inline; filename=\"7_faker_cover.jpg\"; filename*=UTF-8''7_faker_cover.jpg", "encoded_key"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSm5kbUZ5YVdGdWRITXZiMDVvUjNCblJIQm9RVWd6YWtGeFFWUlpPV0Z3U2tWSUwyRTBZemd3WVRCallUUTJZalJtWmpObE16Vm1aV1l5TVRFelltWmxPREptWlRsalpUbGhNalE0WmpWaE9UZ3hZVEk1WkdVek5XUmxNemt4Wm1VNE1HUUdPZ1pGVkRvUVpHbHpjRzl6YVhScGIyNUpJazFwYm14cGJtVTdJR1pwYkdWdVlXMWxQU0kzWDJaaGEyVnlYMk52ZG1WeUxtcHdaeUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuTjE5bVlXdGxjbDlqYjNabGNpNXFjR2NHT3daVU9oRmpiMjUwWlc1MFgzUjVjR1ZKSWc5cGJXRm5aUzlxY0dWbkJqc0dWQT09IiwiZXhwIjoiMjAxOS0wMi0yNFQyMDoxNTo1MS45OTFaIiwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--c8b11cdaa201d28d585f62aaa7c8cf6af75e7cab", "filename"=>"7_faker_cover"}
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

After:

```
Started GET "/rails/active_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--223b806011854805e1e50ca952099bcdbc4d8bdd/7_faker_cover.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%227_faker_cover.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%277_faker_cover.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-24 13:11:37 -0700
Processing by ActiveStorage::DiskController#show as JPEG
  Parameters: {"content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "disposition"=>"inline; filename=\"7_faker_cover.jpg\"; filename*=UTF-8''7_faker_cover.jpg", "encoded_key"=>"[FILTERED]", "filename"=>"7_faker_cover"}
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Most of the change is in the third line, the parameters are a lot shorter. Unfortunately that's pretty much all I could figure out

I am curious if it'd be possible to silence any logs tagged as Disk Storage (the 'Checked if file exists at key:' and 'Generated URL for file at key:' lines):

```
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/representations/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBGQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--6b1335aa96f07d0e8a19178e8d4c65d4a6b6ec60/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdCam9MY21WemFYcGxTU0lOTXpBd2VEVXdNRDRHT2daRlZBPT0iLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6InZhcmlhdGlvbiJ9fQ==--aca35120fd4bdbafe23b34690fa45f96280194c4/7_faker_cover.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-24 13:11:37 -0700
Processing by ActiveStorage::RepresentationsController#show as JPEG
  Parameters: {"signed_blob_id"=>"[FILTERED]", "variation_key"=>"[FILTERED]", "filename"=>"7_faker_cover"}
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/connorshea/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Disk Storage (0.1ms) Checked if file exists at key: variants/oNhGpgDphAH3jAqATY9apJEH/a4c80a0ca46b4ff3e35fef2113bfe82fe9ce9a248f5a981a29de35de391fe80d (yes)
  Disk Storage (276.0ms) Generated URL for file at key: variants/oNhGpgDphAH3jAqATY9apJEH/a4c80a0ca46b4ff3e35fef2113bfe82fe9ce9a248f5a981a29de35de391fe80d (http://localhost:3000/rails/active_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--223b806011854805e1e50ca952099bcdbc4d8bdd/7_faker_cover.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%227_faker_cover.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%277_faker_cover.jpg)
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSm5kbUZ5YVdGdWRITXZiMDVvUjNCblJIQm9RVWd6YWtGeFFWUlpPV0Z3U2tWSUwyRTBZemd3WVRCallUUTJZalJtWmpObE16Vm1aV1l5TVRFelltWmxPREptWlRsalpUbGhNalE0WmpWaE9UZ3hZVEk1WkdVek5XUmxNemt4Wm1VNE1HUUdPZ1pGVkRvUVpHbHpjRzl6YVhScGIyNUpJazFwYm14cGJtVTdJR1pwYkdWdVlXMWxQU0kzWDJaaGEyVnlYMk52ZG1WeUxtcHdaeUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuTjE5bVlXdGxjbDlqYjNabGNpNXFjR2NHT3daVU9oRmpiMjUwWlc1MFgzUjVjR1ZKSWc5cGJXRm5aUzlxY0dWbkJqc0dWQT09IiwiZXhwIjoiMjAxOS0wMi0yNFQyMDoxNjozNy43MTlaIiwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--223b806011854805e1e50ca952099bcdbc4d8bdd/7_faker_cover.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%227_faker_cover.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%277_faker_cover.jpg
Completed 302 Found in 300ms (ActiveRecord: 16.7ms)
```

I assumed these were using Rails' [TaggedLogging](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TaggedLogging.html) functionality, but it doesn't look like they are (see the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.2/activestorage/lib/active_storage/log_subscriber.rb)). Short of monkey-patching ActiveStorage's logger (which seems like a pretty bad idea) I'm not sure of a good way to improve this situation.

Answer (score 4):

```rb
# config/development.rb

ActiveStorage::LogSubscriber.detach_from :active_storage
```

will mute the message `Generated URL for file at key`

Answer (score 2):

I tried the answers above and none of them worked and looking more for a solution, I found this gem that remove the ActiveStorage log (at least on Rails 5.2):
https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/active_storage_silent_logs

As stated in the doc, in your puma.rb set:
`threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 1 }`
if you want the log 100% muted

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the log level for your rails app is set to debug, which is why you're getting so much output. If you definitely want the amount of logging you get with the debug log level but you don't want to see so many messages from active storage you can configure a different logger in your environment config (eg. `config/environments/production.rb`):

```
# set a different logger for ActiveStorage, using the ERROR log level
config.active_storage.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(config.default_log_file, level: Logger::ERROR)
```

This will log to a log file (eg `log/production.log`) but if you'd rather log to the console (for example if you use heroku) then replace `config.default_log_file` with `STDOUT`.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
<!--- turn off logger --->
old_logger = ActiveStorage.logger
ActiveStorage.logger = nil

<!--- turn on logger --->
ActiveStorage.logger = old_logger
```

this code can be used where the code executes that draws the sql to your logs. first turn off the logger, then after the code runs that floods your logs you can turn the logger back on. Or you can load `ActiveStorage.logger = nil` into an initializer (such as `config/initializers/active_storage_logger.rb` and it will turn off all active storage logging.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: Can you show me where you are attempting to nil the logger?

Also, are you referring to your actual development logs or are you referring to the verbose server console content that prints to the screen upon activity?

Comment: @Verty00 I'd say its the console screen upon activity. It's pretty annoying.